# What is the correct way to redirect an old http single page to a completely new https domain?

Tags: web, redirect

I'm trying to set up a permanent redirect from an old http page to an entirely new domain.  The http site where the old page was is now https.

Example-
I would like to Redirect this page:
http://example.net/productpage/

To go to this:
https://newwebsite.com/

I have found similar questions although the answers aren't working for me. Not personally come across this particular issue before. Currently, while working on redirects I have a 404 to homepage redirect plugin on the WP website. But the original http://example.net/productpage/ is in a printed document so not ideal.

After researching I have tried a couple of suggested methods to .htaccess under RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^productpage/$ https://newwebsite.com/ [R=301]

and also:

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.net$ 
RewriteRule ^productpage\$ https://newwebsite.com [R=301,L]

Basically, trying to get the old http page to direct users to another https website

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track, you just need to go over each instruction with a magnifying glass.. https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect /productpage https://newwebsite.com/
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! You are great! It worked. Thank you so much. Sorry for the delay in getting back to you, only just seen you had responded. FAB :-)